# Determine the Steady State current on iR(0+) and voltage vR(0+)

Tags: voltage, steady-state

I am currently reviewing some past quizzes for a Circuits problem, and I am a bit confused by the calculations done at part `D` of the problem:

Could someone explain to me why Vr(0+) is `150V - 300V`? I can see that the voltage is evenly distributed from those two voltage sources, but I don't know how to arrive to that conclusion.

[image]

Comment: I don't know what lead you to say that the voltage is evenly distributed.

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone explain to me why Vr(0+) is 150V - 300V?

[Kirchhoff's Voltage Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_voltage_law_.28KVL.29)

Going counter-clockwise 'round the loop including the two voltage sources and resistor, write by inspection

$$v_R(0+) + 300V - 150V = 0V $$

or

$$v_R(0+) = 150V - 300V $$

Answer (score 1):

From the last circuit, voltage sources are connected to both the leads of resistor R (300V to left and 150V to right).

$$\text{Voltage across R = voltage at right lead of R - voltage at left lead of R}$$
or $$V_R(0^+) = 150V-300V=-150V$$

I don't know what lead you to say that the voltage is evenly distributed.